# Method rewriting not working properly

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am trying to rewrite the method dynamically using following code.

```
"use strict";

define(function (require) {
    var Backbone = require('backbone');

    var TestView = Backbone.View.extend({

        initialize: function () {
            var that = this;
            that.model.on("change", this.render, this);
        },

        render: function () {
            this.initialRender();
            this.$el.html("Work to do everytime");

            this.render = function () {
                this.$el.html("Work to do everytime");
            }
        },
        initialRender: function () {
            console.log("Work to do once only");
        }

    });

    var model = new Backbone.Model();
    var view = new TestView({
        model: model
    });

    view.render();
    view.render();

    view.model.set("testdata", "data");
});
```

I want this output :

```
Work to do once only
```

But I am getting this output:

```
Work to do once only
Work to do once only
```

Can anyone please explain what exactly is happening?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your event handler is already bound to the original version of of the render function. Replacing the this.render reference does not change this fact.

Derick Bailey has written a [blog post](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2013/03/08/method-rewriting-running-with-a-lit-stick-of-dynamite/) describing the problem.